# Is it possible to synchronize final fields in java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to synchronize final fields in java? if so what is the use of that?
Moreover how does synchronizing fields affect the program?

Comment: It is unclear what your first question is, and your second and third questions are quite broad.

Comment: This is completely trivial to test. You then need to understand that it's an object you `synchronized` on, not a field or variable.

Answer (score -1):

**"Final is a keyword or reserved word in java and can be applied to member variables, methods, class and local variables in Java. Once you make a reference final you are not allowed to change that reference and compiler will verify this and raise compilation error if you try to re-initialized final variables in java."**

Go through the below link:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html#ixzz3M5EiJeh1